# Trouble Analyzing Rare (zero-inflated) Target Variable

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, data-analysis

I'm working on an analysis of traffic accident data and I'm trying to understand the association between a  number of categorical dependent variables about the conditions and circumstances of the accidents and my target variable which is the number of fatal injuries in a crash. The problem is that crashes with at least one fatality are only 0.092% of the data. I've made an attempt at a random forest which performs terribly on class 1 and nearly 100% on class 0 and I've made an attempt at a Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial which I'm still struggling to create and evaluate properly. Am I on the right track? Is trying to find these associations even a reasonable goal given almost all of the target is zeros? Are there some other techniques I should be aware of?

Thanks!

P.S. I should add that the categorical variables in question have relatively high cardinality. Several have around 20 different classes and a one that is likely very important one has 40.